# SYNCHRONIZATION started loop

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, synchronization, linux

I'm trying to get `monerod` to work after running `monero-blockchain-prune`. It didn't seem to be working right and I found that `monero-blockchain-import --pop-blocks ...` might help. So I popped off the last 100 blocks, and it fixed the issue, but now it seems to just be stuck on a loop of what I posed below. I tried `--no-sync` and `in-peers 10` but neither have gotten it to work like it was working before.

```
2021-05-21 02:05:41.679 I [142.93.228.111:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2365193 -> 2365471 [Your node is 278 blocks (9.3 hours) behind]
2021-05-21 02:05:41.680 I SYNCHRONIZATION started
2021-05-21 02:05:42.076 I [144.91.122.162:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2365193 -> 2365471 [Your node is 278 blocks (9.3 hours) behind]
2021-05-21 02:05:42.077 I SYNCHRONIZATION started
2021-05-21 02:05:42.978 I [212.83.172.165:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2365193 -> 2365471 [Your node is 278 blocks (9.3 hours) behind]
2021-05-21 02:05:42.978 I SYNCHRONIZATION started
2021-05-21 02:05:43.376 I [144.91.122.162:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2365193 -> 2365471 [Your node is 278 blocks (9.3 hours) behind]
2021-05-21 02:05:43.376 I SYNCHRONIZATION started
2021-05-21 02:05:43.841 I [80.111.125.243:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2365193 -> 2365471 [Your node is 278 blocks (9.3 hours) behind]
2021-05-21 02:05:43.841 I SYNCHRONIZATION started
2021-05-21 02:05:44.238 I [144.91.122.162:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2365193 -> 2365471 [Your node is 278 blocks (9.3 hours) behind]
2021-05-21 02:05:44.238 I SYNCHRONIZATION started
2021-05-21 02:05:44.543 I Host 144.91.122.162 blocked.
2021-05-21 02:05:44.699 I [188.117.224.141:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2365193 -> 2365471 [Your node is 278 blocks (9.3 hours) behind]
2021-05-21 02:05:44.699 I SYNCHRONIZATION started
2021-05-21 02:05:45.249 I [142.93.228.111:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2365193 -> 2365471 [Your node is 278 blocks (9.3 hours) behind]
2021-05-21 02:05:45.249 I SYNCHRONIZATION started
2021-05-21 02:05:45.558 I Host 207.246.77.199 blocked.
2021-05-21 02:05:45.902 I [80.111.125.243:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2365193 -> 2365471 [Your node is 278 blocks (9.3 hours) behind]
2021-05-21 02:05:45.902 I SYNCHRONIZATION started
2021-05-21 02:05:46.222 I [76.22.65.8:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2365193 -> 2365471 [Your node is 278 blocks (9.3 hours) behind]
2021-05-21 02:05:46.222 I SYNCHRONIZATION started
```

Comment: As you popped blocks, you *need* to sync, hence I'm clear why you are using `--no-sync`.

Comment: @jtgrassie I'm very new to this and don't know too much about what's going on. I was just trying anything to get it to work like it used to. Since it just kept looping about syncing, I thought maybe it would help.

Comment: Mason, if you don't know what the flags do, don't use them. Just let your daemon sync.

Comment: @jtgrassie can you tell me what it's doing? This is not how it behaved before the prune.

Comment: From your screenshot, It looks like it knows it's behind, but has been told not to sync. So first things first, don't use flags like `--no-sync`. You *need* it to sync as you stated you popped blocks.

Comment: @jtgrassie that picture is what happens when I just run `monerod`, no flags.

Comment: So leave it running and you should periodically get a message telling you how many blocks synced/remaining there are.

Comment: @jtgrassie that's what used to happen. if you look at the console output I posted, you can see it just stays at X blocks behind - increasing by one every time a new block comes in. It never actually starts syncing

Comment: No. Your snippet only shows a very short period of time. The message that shows "synced/remaining" is infrequent (much bigger gaps of time) and is different to the "new top block candidate" ones you posted). If you "look at the console output" you posted, you'd see it is *not* "increasing by one every time a new block comes in".

Comment: This issue is real, I'm also seeing a lot of " I SYNCHRONIZATION started" messages while doing a full sync. This should not be normal. CPU, RAM, and network usage is also far from 100%. Something is abnormal.